# How to prevent the editor from automaticly inserting a p tag after hr tag?

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using CKEDitor 3.6 and it seems the bug is in my version and not newer one. Currently, I can't switch to the new version.

When clicking on horizontal rule icon from toolbar configured with 
**config.enterMode= CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;**, I get

```
Result:
     <hr />
     <p>&nbsp;</p>


Expected result:
     <hr />
```

I don't want the p tag inserted after hr tag, how can I fix this on CKeditor version 3.6 ?

[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javaxx/pjmkhqbx/)